# Override group policy to render page in document mode 9

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Application is using tomcat. Ive added this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

to one of the jsp files. After going to the page in IE11 and viewing source, i can see the tag shows up right under the title

```
<head>
<title>Create Traveler</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" />
```

however the page is still rendering in document mode 7 because of the group policy. Is there a way to override the group policy in the jsp file or in the tomcat web.xml file?